# Multiple Fragments with same layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

What should I do to make Multiple Fragments with the same layout. I've just created it but can't access widgets separately. I think it's because they have the same ids. How can we reuse the layout file?

example:
Each client represents a tab

---

### Client 1|Client 2|Client 3

[--Name--][--Name--][--Name--]

Client 1,2,3 use the same layout. How can we reuse the layout ?

Comment: first of all do you really need a fragments? why not simple PagerAdapter which wraps the normal Adapter ? fx: http://selvin.pl/SimpleCursorPagerAdapter.java.txt

Comment: Need Dynamic number of Clients?

Comment: and? simple view would be better ... the FragmenPagerAdapter is creating  a fragment for every item ... my solution works in the similar way as ListView it reusing the views so only AFAIK 3 view would be created ...

Comment: of course you can use a fragments but then just use same class for every client ... but with different arguments - **just look at the example from FragmentPagerAdapter docs** ... insted argument "num" pass the client id ... then based on it load right client data in onCreateView(or other more accurate event of fragment lifecycle) ... still if you wana only show data in ViewPager i would go for simple view

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when click the button and manage the fragment

```
  Fragment mFragment1  = new Fragment();
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, mFragment1)
            .addToBackStack("")
            .commit();
```

in this `R.id.frame_container` are replace the new fragment..

Comment: create on Event listener and when swiping than add this code.

Comment: ViewPager,FragmentStatePagerAdapter What shoud i do?

Comment: use ViewPage like this ,.. android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Basically its like this.

For the manager:

```
Fragment fragment = MyFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And for the MyFragment():

```
public class MyFragment extends android.app.Fragment

public MyFragment() {
    // Empty constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy as simple as using fragment state pager adapter
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

There are a ton of examples out there